# C++ Command Line: Output program variable value

Tags: c++, command-line, variable-assignment, introspection

I am writing a drop-down console for my app. Suppose I want to output the value of variable `myvar` by using the following command:

```
]/get myvar
```

Is there a better way than to create a map so that the output is

```
return mymap[argv[0]]; ?
```

In other words, can I associate the input char array "myvar" to the variable named myvar without doing it manually for all the variables in the program.

Comment: Why would you do anything manually? *All* your variables that would be thus exposed would be dynamically managed by a container.

Comment: I fail to get the question...can you try being more precise? Drop-down consoles and command line parameters are kinda different thing...

Comment: I know, but "how" do you associate the user inputted variable char array to the variable itselft ?

Comment: i guess its more related to command line, I want to be able to output the value of variables already present in my program while it is running. So I use a drop-down console and type in /get myvar. But the input is just a char array, how can I associate it with the variable called myvar

Comment: @Smash? What? You want to use the input as a variable name and define the variable as the file name (argv[0])?

Comment: @Smash if you have an user input that is a char* in C(or C++) the only way to deal with it is to parse it yourself. So yes you have to split at whitespaces, maybe "=" whatever your syntax is and map that somehow to your program data. How that happens is up to your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

No.

**Long answer:**

Pfff, no way! After your piece of code is build as a binary, there is no such thing as a variable name. Just some pointers, values on the stack, and so on...

If you want to implement something like this, I would recommend you to go for a scripting library ([Lua](http://www.lua.org/), for example), and manually map some variables so you can read/change those variables via scripts. In this case the console input is basically what you are feeding to the script engine.

[This might be a good reference](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2001-03/msg00048.html).

UPDATE:

In fact, just found the project called [Lua Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lua-cui/).
Seems like it's not maintained anymore, but it doesn't mean it will not work.

Comment: thanks, but I'll stick to C++ and just go through the hassle of creating a std::map for all the variables which might be usefull DX

Comment: @Smash: $100 you're going about this the wrong way. Good design should rarely feel painful.

Comment: maybe, but no worries, it really isn't that painfull after all, just not as satisfying as it could be